# How to retrieve values from nested dictionary given list of keys?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Given a list of strings like so:

```
a_list_of_keys = ['a key', 'heres another', 'oh hey a key']
```

What's a way to retrieve that nested series of keys from a dict like

```
the_value_i_want = some_dict['a key']['heres another']['oh hey a key']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `reduce` with `operator.getitem`.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 100}}}
>>> reduce(getitem, ['a', 'b', 'c'], d)
100
>>> d['a']['b']['c']
100
```

Comment: Nice.  I was thinking I needed something like getitem without even knowing getitem existed.  Thanks!